# Is this intersection of DFAs correct?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm constructing a [deterministic finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA) for a language of all strings defined over $\{0,1\}$ whose length is even and number of $1$s is odd. I constructed each DFA separately and then combined:

[image: dfas and their union]

- Is the given procedure for combining DFAs correct?
  **EDIT:** Originally wrote union; actually taking the intersection.
- Would someone suggest material on constructing DFAs
  given restrictions on length and number of $0$s or $1$s?

According to link given by Merbs, I have developed this FA. [image] 
 This FA does not accept a language of even length.

Comment: Your approach seems correct, but you should use the **intersection** and not the union of the two DFAs.

Comment: I have learnt only 3 methods like union of FAs, concatenation of FAs and closure of FA. I am searching but cant find the intersection of FAs. Can you point me to some useful link?

Comment: From a Google search: [this site](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/fcs/dfas.html) is good, but the gist is that you take the intersection of the accepting states.

Comment: i have visited this link but this provides a specific example not a rule, bcz when we come across some difficult FA then it would be difficult to construct intersection.

Comment: Given two DFAs with $m$ and $n$ states, constructing a DFA with $mn$ states (with each state representing a pair of states in the original DFAs) *is* the rule; and then you can minimize the resulting DFA through a set of (mostly heuristic?) procedures.

Comment: As for your second question, is this what you're looking for: a DFA restricting the length of input to $n$, requires $n+1$ states in a chain; a DFA restricting the number of $0$s to $n$ and $1$s to $m$ requires $mn+1$ interleaving states.

Comment: @Merbs please see the edit, i have developed this FA according to your link, please correct me where i am making mistake.

Comment: The best way is to test it: does it correctly accept 01 and 110001, and reject 11100, 01001 and 0110? In the original DFAs, what were the accept states? It should be the intersection of that set.

Comment: But it seems as though yours accepts the string 1 which isn't of even length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is called the *Product Constuction* - given DFAs $M_1$ and $M_2$, we can construct $M=M_1\times M_2$:

- $M$ consists of pairs of states from its constituent DFAs, so if the original DFAs 
  have states $A,B,C$ and $x,y,z$, the product would be $\{Ax,Ay,Az,Bx,By,Bz,Cx,Cy,Cz\}$.
- The transition function is updated such that if on a particular step, a string would cause $M_1$ to transition from state $A$ to $B$ and $M_2$ to transition from $x$ to $y$, then the product would transition from $Ax$ to $By$
- The initial state is the pair consisting of the initial states of the constituent DFAs (i.e. $Ax$).
- If we are constructing the DFA that determines whether **both** of
  the two constituent DFAs would accept the string, then the accept
  states of $M$ is the **intersection** (those pairs made up of accept states from both).
  If we are constructing the DFA that determines whether **either** of the two
  constituent DFAs would accept the string, then the accept states of
  $M$ is the **union**  (those pairs made up of accept states from either).
  In your example, $x_1$ and $y_0$ are the accept states of $M_1$ and $M_2$; the intersection would be $\{x_1y_0\}$ while the union would be $\{x_1y_0,x_1y_1,x_0y_0\}$.

I’ve included some other DFAs regarding restrictions on length for reference.

[image: example dfas]

Comment: In cases of union, should the set of accepting states not be $M_1Q_2 \cup Q_1M_2$? (Not that anyone would use this construction for union; in that cases, $|Q_1|+|Q_2|+1$ states suffice as opposed to $|Q_1||Q_2|$ this construction yields. At least if we are talking NFA.)

Comment: @Raphael, your comment, while correct, was complicated enough that I didn't understand it without further thought, so I attempted to "laymenize" it. If you'd like to edit my answer to include a discussion on NFAs, you can make it a community wiki (or add your own answer).

Comment: @Merbs, thanks for your help and answer. Sorry for late reply but i tried this method to other FA`s and this was successful.

Answer (score 1):

OK, "laymanized" a bit. Take DFAs $M_1 = (Q_1, \Sigma, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$ and $M_2 = (Q_2, \Sigma, \delta_2, q_2, F_2)$. Consider the DFA $M = (Q_1 \times Q_2, \Sigma, \delta, (q_1, q_2), F_1 \times F_2)$, where $\delta$ is defined by:
$$
\delta((q', q''), a) = (\delta_1(q', a), \delta_2(q'', a))
$$
The idea is that the state of $M$ records the states in which $M_1$ and $M_2$ would be if they processed the string separately. $M$ accepts only if both of them do.

Comment: Not sure in which way this is "laymanized"; this is the (correct) formal definition for the product construction. You should mention how the state set of $M$ can be reduced in many cases; nobody wants to draw all that crap.