# Show that the language of strings not in the union of two regular languages is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Given languages $L_1,L_2$, defines $X(L_1,L_2)$ by

$\qquad X(L_1,L_2) = \{w \mid w \not\in L_1 \cup L_2 \}$

If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular, how can we show that $X(L_1,L2)$ is also regular?

Comment: Hint: use closure properties of regular languages.

Comment: Is this an exercise? What have you tried?

Comment: see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6893/

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to show that a language is regular (check the question [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular))

Specifically for the language in your question, start with DFAs for $L_1$ and $L_2$ and try to construct an NFA for $X(L_1,L_2)$ using them. More details below:

> Note that $X(L_1,L_2) = \overline{L_1} \cap \overline{L_2}$.
>  From the DFA of $L_1$ construct the DFA of $\overline {L_1}$ (making any final state not-final, and vice-versa). Do the same for $L_2$.  Intersection of regular languages can be constructed via product machine (see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6893/intersection-of-dfas)).
>  [Of course, if you already know that a complement of a regular language is also regular, and so the intersection of two regular languages – you are done without constructing those DFAs..]

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Zach's comment, you (*should*) know the following things:

1. If $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are regular languages, then $L_{1} \cup L_{2}$ is a regular language.
2. If $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are regular languages, then $L_{1} \cap L_{2}$ is a regular language.
3. If $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are regular languages, then $L_{1} \cdot L_{2}$ is a regular language.
4. If $L$ is a regular language, then $L^{\ast}$ is a regular language.
5. If $L$ is a regular language, then $\bar{L}$ is a regular language.

Now you should be able to pick a few of these that combined make up your $X$ language function/operator/whatever you call something like that (well, it's just a language defined in terms of others).

Just for some background, proofs for these properties can be found (IN A REALLY LARGE FONT) [here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/slides/rs2.pdf).

Give this a go, if you're really stuck, I'll put a bit more in the spoilers below (but with little explanation).

> $X(A_{1},A_{2}) = \overline{A_{1}\cup A_{2}} = \bar{A_{1}}\cap\bar{A_{2}}$.