# Intersection of regular and not regular

Tags: regular-languages, automata

$L_1=\{a^n\mid n\ge1\}$ is regular and
$L_2=\{a^{n^2}\mid n\ge1\}$ is non-regular. 
We know that $L_1\cap L_2$ is regular but,
here $L_1\cap L_2=L_2$; and $L_2$ is not regular. How is this possible?

Comment: We *don't* know that when $L_1$ is regular and $L_2$ isn't, their intersection is always regular.  Consider $L_1=\Sigma^*$.

Comment: @reinierpost Actually, the example in the question *is* $L_1=\Sigma^*$ for $\Sigma=\{a\}$.

Comment: @David Richerby: Yes, my remark is a clumsy way to clarify that the resulting language can always be equal to whatever you pick $L_2$ to be.

Comment: In your specific case, $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_2$, non-regular.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on David's answer, you are confusing between the next two claims.

**Claim 1** if $L_1,L_2$ are regular, then $L_1 \cap L_2$ is also regular.
(proof: construct the product DFA, e.g., [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6893/is-this-intersection-of-dfas-correct))

**Claim 2** if $L_1$ is regular, but $L_2$ is not, then $L_1\cap L_2$ can be either regular or not-regular.
(proof: Let $L_2$ be some non-regular language. If $L_1=\Sigma^*$ then $L_1\cap L_2=L_2$ which is non-regular by its definition. On the other hand, if $L_1=\emptyset$ then $L_1\cap L_2=L_1=\emptyset$ which *is* regular)

Comment: thanx dear for clearig my point,its cod'n is either or, but not necessary..,thnk u.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ and $L'$ are both regular then, yes, $L\cap L'$ is regular. But, if $L'$ is not regular, then all the bets are off, as your example shows.